# for loop inside else if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

i'm feeling a little stupid about this because the answer HAS to be obvious, but i've been thinking about it for an hour now and i'm clueless. I am filling some LinkedLists with conditions (the order is important), but one of the conditions actually requires a for loop to see if it is true.
This is the piece of code i'm talking about, and after the first "else if", i need a second "else if" but to verify is the statement is true, i need a for loop. Of course as it is the code doesn't work, so if someone could tell me what i need to do in order to get the desired result, i would be very grateful! thanks

```
for (Region neut : visibleRegions){
  if (neut.ownedByPlayer("neutral") && getSubRegionsOwnedByPlayerName(neut.getSuperRegion(), opponentName).isEmpty()){
    if ( getSubRegionsOwnedByPlayerName(neut.getSuperRegion(),myName).size()==neut.getSuperRegion().getSubRegions().size()-1 ){
            priorityNeutralRegions_0.add(neut);
        }
        else if ( getSubRegionsOwnedByPlayerName(neut.getSuperRegion(), myName).size()==neut.getSuperRegion().getSubRegions().size()-2 ){
            priorityNeutralRegions_1.add(neut);
        }
        else{
            for (Region neig : neut.getNeighbors()){
                if ( neig.getSuperRegion().ownedByPlayer(myName)){
                    priorityNeutralRegions_2.add(neut);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ( !getSubRegionsOwnedByPlayerName(neut.getSuperRegion(), myName).isEmpty()){
            priorityNeutralRegions_3.add(neut);
        }
        else{
            priorityNeutralRegions_4.add(neut);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add a language tag please

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what part doesn't work?

Comment: This code is pretty messy. I would refactor it (maybe add some methods in place of loops, etc) before you work on functionality. That'll make it **easier to read** and thus **easier to debug**

Comment: wow if you think this is messy, you don't want to see the other 1000 lines of code :). I already used a lot of methods in the if statements, it's just that the name of the methods are really long, but i don't see how i could refractor it more. Sorry if i wasn't clear, my problem was on how to include a "for loop" in an "else if" condition, and the answer is to wrap the for loop in a method and call it in the "else if" condition (thanks to fstd)

Comment: Aside from the function solution, you could place the last if/else set INSIDE the else leg that contains the loop, so that you only entered it if the loop "failed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap whatever the loop does in a function, call that function as part of the `else if` condition.